# Retrieving results for query from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to query a MySQL database. I have the following. `$name` keeps changing in a loop. (`$query` is a sample query here)

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE name='$name';";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());        
echo "$result<br/>";
While ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo $row["id"] . " - " . $row["name"];
}
```

with the `echo "$result<br/>"` it just prints something like `Resource id #`. Nothing from `$row` is printed. The MySQL connection is fine. If I run the query without PHP, it works fine. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct, you'll get nothing from $result until you use some function like mysql_fetch_array() or mysql_fetch_assoc() like you do in your loop.

Comment: The while loop does not print anything. Is there anything that I might be missing?

Comment: $row["name"] doens't exist in your result because you only selected 'id' in your query. If your error reporting is off, the echo won't print. Try without the $row["name"]?

Comment: Should print the id anyway. I guess the query doesn't return any result (empty $name in query?). Try echo mysql_num_rows($result), should be > 0 if the query is correct.

Comment: When I echo mysql_num_rows($result), I get all 0. I do not understand. There query is correct and runs fine otherwise. Why is it not retrieving anything in this case???